# Live wallpaper causes textures to appear white in app on first launch

Tags: java, android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to create a live wallpaper for my app.

Everything works, unfortunately, when I first open my app while my live wallpaper is installed, everything appears white. When I leave and resume my app, suddenly everything works.

Here are some logs:

Broken:

```
06-28 13:21:19.936: D/AndEngine(6680): main.onCreateScene @(Thread: 'GLThread 58')
06-28 13:21:19.960: D/AndEngine(6680): main.onPopulateScene @(Thread: 'GLThread 58')
06-28 13:21:19.960: D/AndEngine(6680): main.onGameCreated @(Thread: 'GLThread 58')
06-28 13:21:19.967: D/AndEngine(6680): main.onSurfaceChanged(Width=480,  Height=854) @(Thread: 'GLThread 58')
```

When works, on resume:

```
 06-28 13:21:53.944: D/AndEngine(6680): main.onSurfaceCreated @(Thread: 'GLThread 58')
 06-28 13:21:53.944: D/AndEngine(6680): main.onReloadResources @(Thread: 'GLThread 58')
 06-28 13:21:53.944: D/AndEngine(6680): main.onResumeGame @(Thread: 'GLThread 58')
 06-28 13:21:53.952: D/AndEngine(6680): main.onSurfaceChanged(Width=480,  Height=854) @(Thread: 'GLThread 58')
```

Where should I be looking to debug this problem? Is there some way I can force reload the resources the same way they are loaded on the resume?

If you need more information about the bug please let me know.

Thanks in advance!<3

Comment: Are you sure your textures are being sent to the gfx card before drawing? Also are you sure that you are drawing with the correct texture ID?

Comment: No, I'm not sure of either. How would I check?

Comment: Can you post the main class so we can see what you are doing then.

Comment: May be there is somthing wrong with the visbility flag.